# Last Status By Date and Count

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I want to extract the last status of a item by date from the sample data given below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4I5W.png

I want the following result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDF55.png

Can this be achieved using a formula or PivotTables?

Answer (score 0):

With pivot table you can easily extract the max date of each item. But the status will be problematic.
So, the best way to do it, is not with a pivot table. but with 3 steps.

1) copy your item list to another sheet to the first column. (I will assume the your first sheet is Sheet1 and the 2nd is Sheet2) choose the entire column in the 2nd sheet and remove duplicates. (date ribbon -> remove duplicates)

2) find your max data for each item.
lets assume your first rows is header so in the 2nd rows on column b enter:

```
=max(if(Sheet1!b:b=b3,Sheet1!a:a,""))
```

Note that this an array formula so you have to enter this using ctrl+shift+enter

Now drag this formula to the end of rows

3) find the last status of each item

you have to do double lookup formula
 on c2 enter:

```
=index(Sheet1!c:c,match(a2&b2,Sheet1!b:b&Sheet1!a:a,0),1)
```

Again, that this an array formula so you have to enter this using ctrl+shift+enter

And again, drag this formula to the end of rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works with a bit of modification. The second formula needs to be different in order to pick the status from column C: =INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,MATCH(A2&B2,Sheet1!B:B&Sheet1!A:A,0),1).

Comment: Sheri, if it answers your question, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this can be done only with formulas and *without copying the data in another worksheet*.

Assuming your data is in the range `A1:C16` *(change as needed)* then you can enter the following *Array Formulas (press [Ctrl]+Shift]+[Enter] together)*:

Enter *"Item"* in `E1` and this array formula in `E2` then copy down till last record *(`E16` for this sample)*

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$16,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(E$1:E1,$B$2:$B$16),0)*1),"")
```

Enter *"Date”* in `F1` and this array formula in `F2` then copy down till last record *(`F16` for this sample)*

```
=IF($E2="","",MAX(IF($B$2:$B$16=E2,$A$2:$A$16,"")))
```

Finally Enter *“Status”* in `G1` and this array formula in `G2` then copy down till last record *(`G16` for this sample)*

```
=IF($E2="","",INDEX($C$2:$C$16,MATCH($E2&$F2,$B$2:$B$16&$A$2:$A$16,0),1))
```

Ranges within the formulas should be adjusted as needed, no need to point to all rows in the worksheet.